# dropdown menu mysql PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

im new on PHP.
i have problem on  mydropdown  menu program. 
i create table with name id and name .connected with mysql database
this what i want,
*when i choose  id 1  on dropdown menu 1 then dropdown menu 2 "show only" name "ex:dk" and other example 'id 2 " = name :"James "*....

```
     <?php
     /*---START -----*/
     $host   ='localhost';
     $user   ='root';
     $pass   ='';
     $db     ='sqldumb';

     $kon    =mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
       if(!$kon)
         die('EROR '.mysql_error());
          $dbkon  =mysql_select_db($db);
             if(!$dbkon)
              die('EROR '.mysql_error());

      /*-------END ------*/

      $sql = '';
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cahkos");

      $sql .= '<select>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
          $sql .= "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['id']."</option>";
             }
            $sql .= '</select>';
       ?>


       <?php
       $sql1 = '';
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cahkos Where name  = '.$row[id].' );

         $sql1 .= '<select>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {
                $pilihan1 .= "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
             }
         $sql1 .= '</select>';
       ?>


    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <table align=center  >
         <tr>
            <td font-size=100>choose ID</td>
            <td><?php echo $sql;?></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td font-size=100>choose Name</td>
            <td><?php echo $sql;?></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
  </body>
```

Comment: Well, you are displaying one select box twice. So if you replace the second `$sql` with `$sql1` it should work?

Comment: DOn't use the mysql_* funtions. they are deprecated: http://www.php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: What is the exact error you're running into? The code above already has a syntax error.

Comment: i already edit my program  code  with $sql, &sql and  for dropdown menu "Choose Name" to call name list                                                    with $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cahkos Where name  = '.$row[id].' ");  but stiil cannot show my list name row

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cahkos Where name  = '.$row[id].' );
```

should be this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cahkos Where name  = '".$row['id']."'" );
```